# Vectorized count values within range

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a vectorized approach to count values within interval, e.g.

```
def count_within_interval(
    x: np.array, lower_bound: np.array, upper_bound: np.array
) -> float:
```

I would like to avoid a for loop over the elements, something like this

`float((x[(x >= lower_bound) * (x < upper_bound)]).sum()) / len(x)`

Comment: What output do you need? please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do that with numpy:

```
len(x[np.logical_and(x >= lower_bound, x < upper_bound)])
```

you're basically getting all the element in [lower_bound, upper_bound[ and returning how many elements you get